# IDE doesn't showing any error but Jasper Report is not pooping up while sending filtered data by filttering attribute of HTML form in the borowser

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

IDE doesn't showing any error but Jasper Report is not pooping  in the browser

Form from which I'm sending value of attribute to the controller --

```
<form:form method="POST" role="form" modelAttribute="labDevice"
                              action="${contextPath}${action}?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"
                              class="form-horizontal" data-validation="true" data-ajax-submit="true" novalidate="novalidate" target="_blank">
                       <spring:bind  path="divId.id">
                           <div class="form-group ${(not empty status.errorMessage) ? ' has-error':''}">
                               <label for="inputDivId.id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Division</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-9">
                                   <form:select name="divId"  class="form-control"
                                                 data-change-pull="zillaId.id|divId.id|${contextPath}/zilla-list"
                                                 data-selected="${labDevice.divId.id}" data-itemLabel="divName"
                                                 data-itemValue="id" data-validation="trim|is_exist[divId.id]|integer|required"
                                                 path="divId.id" id="inputDivId.id">
                                       <form:option value="0"> --SELECT--</form:option>
                                       <form:options items="${divList}" itemLabel="divName" itemValue="id"></form:options>
                                   </form:select>
                                   <form:errors path="divId.id" cssClass="help-block text-danger" element="span"/>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </spring:bind><spring:bind path="zillaId.id">
                       <div class="form-group ${(not empty status.errorMessage) ? ' has-error':''}">
                           <label for="inputZillaId.id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Zilla</label>
                           <div class="col-sm-9">
                               <form:select name="zillaId"  class="form-control"
                                             data-change-pull="upaZillaId.id|zillaId.id|${contextPath}/upaZilla-list"
                                             data-selected="${labDevice.zillaId.id}"
                                             data-itemLabel="zillaName"
                                             data-itemValue="id"
                                             data-validation="trim|is_exist[zillaId.id]|integer|required"
                                             path="zillaId.id"
                                             id="inputZillaId.id">
                                   <form:option value="0"> --SELECT--</form:option>
                                   <form:options items="${zillaNameList}" itemLabel="zillaName" itemValue="id"></form:options>
                               </form:select>
                               <form:errors path="zillaId.id" cssClass="help-block text-danger" element="span"/>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </spring:bind>
                       <spring:bind path="upaZillaId.id">
                           <div class="form-group ${(not empty status.errorMessage) ? ' has-error':''}">
                               <label for="inputUpaZillaId.id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">UpaZilla</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-9">
                                   <form:select name="upaZillaId" class="form-control"
                                                data-change-pull="locationId.id|upaZillaId.id|${contextPath}/location-list"
                                                data-selected="${labDevice.upaZillaId.id}"
                                                data-itemLabel="upaZillaName"
                                                data-itemValue="id"
                                                data-validation="trim|is_exist[upaZillaId.id]|integer|required"
                                                path="upaZillaId.id"
                                                id="inputUpaZillaId.id">
                                       <form:option value="0"> --SELECT--</form:option>
                                       <form:options items="${upaZillaNameList}" itemLabel="upaZillaName" itemValue="id"></form:options>
                                   </form:select>
                                   <form:errors path="upaZillaId.id" cssClass="help-block text-danger" element="span"/>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </spring:bind>
                       <spring:bind path="locationId.id">
                           <div class="form-group ${(not empty status.errorMessage) ? ' has-error':''}">
                               <label for="inputLocationId.id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-9">
                                   <form:select name="locationId"  class="form-control"
                                                 data-change-pull="labId.id|locationId.id|${contextPath}/lab-list"
                                                 data-selected="${labDevice.locationId.id}"
                                                 data-itemLabel="locationName"
                                                 data-itemValue="id"
                                                 data-validation="trim|is_exist[locationId.id]|integer|required"
                                                 path="locationId.id"
                                                 id="inputLocationId.id">
                                       <form:option value="0"> --SELECT--</form:option>
                                       <form:options items="${locationList}" itemLabel="locationName" itemValue="id"></form:options>
                                   </form:select>
                                   <form:errors path="locationId.id" cssClass="help-block text-danger" element="span"/>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </spring:bind>
                       <spring:bind path="labId.id">
                           <div class="form-group ${(not empty status.errorMessage) ? ' has-error':''}">
                               <label for="inputLabId.id" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lab</label>
                               <div class="col-sm-9" style="width: 973px;">
                                   <form:select name="labId"  class="form-control selectpicker" data-selected="${labDevice.labId.id}"
                                                 data-itemLabel="labName"
                                                 data-live-search="true" data-itemValue="id"
                                                 data-validation="trim|is_exist[labId.id]|integer"
                                                 path="labId.id" id="inputLabId.id">
                                       <form:option value="0"> --SELECT--</form:option>
                                       <form:options items="${labList}" itemLabel="labName" itemValue="id"></form:options>
                                   </form:select>
                                   <form:errors path="labId.id" cssClass="help-block text-danger" element="span"/>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </spring:bind>


                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5">
                               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  data-target="_blank"> &nbsp; Save &nbsp; </button>
                              <%-- &nbsp; &nbsp;
                               <a href="#DeviceByLocationReport/index" role="button" class="btn btn-warning">Cancel</a>--%>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </form:form>
```

Method of the controller is----

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/generateReport" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getRpt1l(Model model, HttpServletResponse response ,
                        @RequestParam(value = "divId.id", required = false) Integer divId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "zillaId.id", required = false) Integer zillaId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "upaZillaId.id", required = false) Integer upaZillaId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "locationId.id", required = false) Integer locationId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "labId.id", required = false) Integer labId,
                        @ModelAttribute("labDevice") LabDevice labDevice, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws JRException, IOException {

       JasperReportsPdfView view=new JasperReportsPdfView();

        if (divId!=0 && zillaId!=0 && upaZillaId!=0 && locationId!=0 && labId!=0)
            view.setUrl("classpath:/report/deviceByLocation.jrxml");
        view.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        Map<String,Object> params =new HashMap<String,Object>();
        params.put("devicedatasource",deviceByLocationService.report(divId,zillaId,upaZillaId,locationId,labId));
        return new ModelAndView(view,params);



    }
```

while generating report without HTTP form the report was generating.
But after adding HTML form for filtering data to show in report, the report is not generating. 
I also tried different process same thing is happening.
so, what can i do now.

Comment: Is there anyone who can solve the prblm????????

Comment: hello, is there anyone?????